# Matrix, satisfying $A^T=p(A)$

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ be real square matrix, satisfying  $A^T=p(A)$  for some polynomial $$p(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$$ such that $a_0\neq 0$.

I have to prove that $A$ is invertible and I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Do you know about normal matrices?

Comment: Yes. Normal matrix is diagonalizable/ But what about invertability?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint.* Suppose $Ax=0$. Now consider the quantity $x^TA^Tx$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A^T=p(A)$ commutes with $A$, we can simultaneously unitarily upper-triangularise $A,A^T$, hence diagonalise $A,A^T$ (using $A^T=p(A)$).  So the eigenvalues of $A$ satisfies $\bar\lambda=p(\lambda)$, hence $\lambda\neq 0$ (since $a_0\neq 0$).

Comment: You don't necessarily have $A = A^T$.  For example, if $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ then $A^T = A^3$ but $A$ is not symmetric.

Comment: That two matrices commute doesn't necessarily mean they can be (simultaneously or not( diagonalizable. There are commuting non-diagonalizable matrices...

Comment: The same example I gave before shows $A$ doesn't necessarily have to be diagonalizable as a real matrix: so this would need to go into complex territory.  Then, you might need to be careful about how $A^T$ translates.  My thought is that if $\lambda$ is a complex eigenvalue of $A$ then $\bar \lambda = p(\lambda)$ - using the representation theorem that a normal real matrix is orthogonally similar to a block-diagonal matrix with diagonal blocks of the form $\begin{bmatrix} \lambda \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} a&-b\\b&a \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Yes I made a typo.  Meant $\bar\lambda=p(\lambda)$ instead of  $\lambda=p(\lambda)$.  It is immediate from $A^\dagger=p(A)$ without needing representation theorem of normal matrices (we are given that for the original $A$).